# runtime error?This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"?

Tags: asp.net

When i uploaded my web application online and run the application i am getting this error.
 To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".I search in google for the solution i did not get any solution.

and this is my web.config file code

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="200000" maxRequestLength="300000"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
<pages enableViewStateMac="false" enableEventValidation="false"  >
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<!--
      Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
      symbols into the compiled page. Because this
      affects performance, set this value to true only
      during development.
-->
<compilation debug="true" >
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

</httpModules>
```

please can u help me. i place the total web.config code but it is now showing total

Answer (score 5):

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
```

should be inside of

```
<system.web>

...

</system.web>
```

Also, make sure that your **machine.config** (not web.config) does NOT have this line (when debugging):

```
<deployment retail="true" />
```

If it does, this will override your **web.config** customErrors setting.  Change this line in **maching.config** to:

```
<deployment retail="false" />
```

Comment: CutomErrors tag is with in the system.web only

Comment: i not found this tag in my config file

Comment: @filp wher can i get this Mahcine.config file i have only web.config file

Comment: I did not have the <deployment retail="true" /> but the problem was not solve until i add <deployment retail="false" /> in the <System.web> on the maching.config Just FYI  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

More details about `customError` here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx